# Using JNI so files on a dynamic web project(Apache Tomcat Server)

Tags: java, web-services, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, tomcat8

I am making a dynamic web project, which requires to use an external jar file. That jar uses several JNI so files. Now I have the jar and all the required so files. I have added the jar to the java build path, but I am not sure how to introduce the so files to the tomcat server.

I tried adding path to the so file as "LD_LIBRARY_PATH":

> (Properties->Run/Debug Settings->edit->Environment->Select) and also
>   adding the path to "java.library.path"(Run
>   As->RunConfigurations->Tomcat v8 Server->Arguments->VM arguments)
>   flag.

Still it is not working, I am getting below error, whenever the my code is trying to access functions/classes from the above mentioned jar:

> *SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [org.iotivity.simulator.agent.LaunchSimulator] in context with path
>   [/SimulatorAgent] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an
>   exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.oic.simulator.server.SimulatorResource$Type   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>     at
>   org.iotivity.simulator.agent.LaunchSimulator.doPost(LaunchSimulator.java:86)
>     at
>   org.iotivity.simulator.agent.LaunchSimulator.doGet(LaunchSimulator.java:45)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)*

I have tried the same code with a simple Java Application, and it works fine by setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Mushfiqul, welcome to SO. Could you have a look at how you could format your question better? It would be great for the community.

Comment: It looks like the JAR file hasn't been deployed to the the web application. Check the contents of WEB-INF/lib for the deployed application to see if the JAR is present.

Comment: @MarkThomas: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, My web service was supposed to be a service only, without any user interface. So there was no WEB-INF folder. I made the folder and placed the jar and the so files in  WEB-INF/lib. Now my previuos problem is solved. But still, it can not find the so files:  "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Actually, it can find the initial so file, but another so file is used in the 1st so(both are residing in the same directory), and this time it is getting java.link.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is a `ClassNotFoundException`, which would suggest that the JAR isn't properly included. If there was a problem with the native library, you'd get a `UnsatisfiedLinkError` instead. To make the JAR available to Tomcat, you'd need to add it to the classpath (`-classpath=/path/to/your.jar`) or include it in your WAR. The latter depends on your build system, but if you use Maven it's rather easy using the `maven-shade-plugin` (this only works for the JAR though, the native code you'll have to keep on distributing separately). Hope that helps!